# Microdata for offering a boat charter with different prices according to the time of the year

Tags: microdata, schema.org

Example page is: http://www.intercharter.com/IC/charter_card_en.php?sez=c&id=204

This page shows a boat and then a table with cabin charter rates and whole-boat charter rates, that vary according to the time of the year. I'd like to add schema.org microdata and I wonder how I should treat the rates table.

Should I create 2 Events for each row of the table (one for the cabin charter and one for whole-boat charter) and then an Offer nested in each event?

Or should I just create 2 Offers (and no Event) for each row and use availabilityStarts and availabilityEnd to describe the From/To dates of the pricelist?

In either case, should I nest the whole table in AggregateOffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or should I just create 2 Offers (and no Event) for each row and use availabilityStarts and availabilityEnd to describe the From/To dates of the pricelist?

Yes, I think that would be (more) appropriate.

An alternative could be to have one `Event` per destination and nest all available `Offer`s (via [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers)) under it:

```
Event: Yacht tour from xyz to Cyclades
  offers → Offer: a cabin, available from 01/05/2014 to 31/05/2014, 970 EUR
  offers → Offer: whole yacht, available from 01/05/2014 to 31/05/2014, 11140 EUR
  offers → Offer: a cabin, available from 01/06/2014 to 30/06/2014, 1030 EUR
  offers → Offer: whole yacht, available from 01/06/2014 to 30/06/2014, 13140 EUR
  …
Event: Yacht tour from xyz to Sporades
  offers → Offer: a cabin, available from 01/07/2014 to 31/08/2014, 1190 EUR
  offers → Offer: whole yacht, available from 01/07/2014 to 31/08/2014, 15140 EUR
```

(might be tricky with table markup)

However, Schema.org defines that [`Event`](http://schema.org/Event) is for a *specific* event, "happening at a certain time and location". So using `Event` might not be appropriate here.

> In either case, should I nest the whole table in AggregateOffer?

No. [`AggregateOffer`](http://schema.org/AggregateOffer) is a more specific [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer) (i.e., a sub-type), not a container for several `Offer`s. So either use `Offer` or `AggregateOffer`.

`AggregateOffer` could make sense if you want to specify how many cabins/yachts are available/left (via [`offerCount`](http://schema.org/offerCount)) for each timeframe.

Comment: Thank you Unor, what you say makes a lot of sense.

Comment: But I've just realized that although this markup would be the most appropriate, Google will not like it, because it only accepts one Offer per page. So the only solution might be to use aggregateOffer (in not  a very appropriate way) with minPrice corresponding to the low season price. The truth is that we do what we do mainly to please search engines and we have to bend to their likings, even though the best theoretical approach would be different.